# Crystal reports:concatenate details section of each report into single detail

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I would like concatenate details section of each report into single detail section.  For example (each section contains different data)

Detail A 
Detail B
Detail C
where ever is in B, C would like to display A since A, B, C have same date

so that report can only display A, B, C in Detail A

thank you so much for your help

Comment: Show some sample data or sample output to help anyone trying to figure out what exactly you want.

Comment: you can apply suppress if duplicated either in section (based on formula ) or field